# trying to check if i am connected to specific network on python

Tags: python, networking

I am trying to check if i am connected to home netwrok or not so i made a function called get_network_name, i call this function and it returns the name of current network as a string, my home netwrok called T2 when i print the output of the function it prints T2 as expected put in the code when i am trying to check the name of the network the comparison doesn't go as excpected
here is get_network_name function code

```
def get_network_name():
    out = subprocess.check_output('netsh wlan show interfaces').decode("utf-8")
    for line in out.split("\n"):
        if "SSID" in line:
            return line.split(": ")[1]
```

when i try to print its output it prints
`T2`
as expected put when it try this piece of code

```
  home_network = "T2"
  if str(get_network_name)==home_network:
    print("you are connected to T2 network (home network)")
  else : print("you are not on home network \n current network name is ",get_network_name())
```

the output is

```
you are not on home network
 current network name is  T2
```

while i am excpecting to get you are connected to home netwrok as name in the condition is identical to the output of the function
i tried also without the str function it returns the same result

Comment: You have `str(get_network_name)` instead of `str(get_network_name())`.  I make that same mistake all the time.

Comment: i think you can call the functions in python by the two ways

Comment: That's not correct, if you call a function you need the `()`. Just try a  `print(get_network_name)` and a `print(get_network_name())`. Btw. you do not need the `str` in your `if`

Comment: You are incorrect.  You need the `()`.  Did you even try my suggestion before writing your comment?

Comment: i am still having the same incorrect output after adding `()`  btw

Comment: i am sorry you are right if I am using `get_network_name` it prints the function address but it if I use `get_network_name()` it prints the right output, thankyou @FrankYellin ,
you are right @OcasoProtal

Answer (score 0):

I have got a solution
I tried to get `len(home_network)` it prints that it has a length of 2 while `len(current_network)` it prints that it has a length of 3 so I solved this problem by comparing the all characters except the last one in ' current_network  ' here is the code after eddeting

```
if current_Network[:len(current_Network)-1]==home_network:
print("you are connected to T2 network (home network)")
```

else :
print("you are not on home network \n current network name is ",get_network_name())

the output as expected was

```
you are connected to T2 network (home network)
```

Edit :

```
  current_Network=get_network_name();
```